# Statistical test for categorical data dealing with behaviour pre/post

Tags: categorical-data, pre-post-comparison

I am looking for help with what statistical test I should use to analyse my data.

I want to know if there is a statistically significant difference between the animals behaviour before and after interaction with a tour vessel

There are five types of behaviour, and for each encounter I know what the behaviour was pre approach and post approach.

I have made a table of straight Y/N whether there was a change, and also the proportion of encounters where each behaviour was occurring pre and post. But i'm not sure where any means fit in and how I could analyse this.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your description of the data, I am assuming these behaviors aren't ordered, and that only one behavior was recorded for each animal at pre and post exposure. If this is the case, you have "nominal paired data".

You may want to consider what is called a marginal homogeneity or Stuart-Maxwell test.  The null hypothesis of this test in the context of your experiment would be that the probability of observing each behavior before the interaction with a tour vessel is the same as the probability of observing each behavior after the interaction with a tour vessel. You also are make the assumption that the behaviors of one animal are independent of the behaviors of other animals, so they should not be effecting each other's outcome.

[Here](http://statkat.com/stat-tests/marginal-homogeneity-stuart-maxwell-test.php) is a solid reference on this test.